# Is Access database file actually a zip file?

Tags: ms-access

As you may know Microsoft Office files from 2007 version on, which are distinguished by 'x' in their extension, are actually zip files. Is this true for Access database files too?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unlike other Microsoft Office files like .docx and .xlsx, Microsoft Access .accdb and .mdb files are **not** compressed (zip) files.